# CUDA error: invalid device ordinal when using python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I'm trying to excute a code, but I keep geting this error when compiling this piece of code:

```
  import tensorflow as tf

  from xba import XBA

  import torch

  torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4]).to(device="cuda:2")
```

torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4]).to(device="cuda:2") generates this error: "

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid device ordinal
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the 
stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
```

AnyIdea about the origine of the bug, it's just the first line of code!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"cuda:2"
```

selects the third GPU in your system.  If you don't have 3 GPUs (at least) in your system, you'll get this error.

Assuming you have at least 1 properly installed and set up CUDA GPU available, try:

```
"cuda:0"
```

Comment: Using cuda:0 throws an error if you have one GPU in the system, but still, the problem of "CUDA warning: invalid device ordinal" persists. Python 3, PyTorch 1.13 @ AWS SageMaker